# How do I retrieve a value from a variable in a for loop?

Tags: ant

I have a for loop like the following:

```
<property name="audi" value="germany" />
<property name="toyota" value="japan" />

<for list="audi,toyota" param="car">
    <sequential>
       <echo>@{@{car}}</echo>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to echo the value "germany" then "japan", but it doesn't - it displays `@{@{car}}`

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it...

```
@{@{car}}
```

needs to be:

```
${@{car}}
```